# Femtosecond-Camera Update

Tags: photons, laser, camera, technology

Hopefully I've posted in the correct page. Honestly, I wasn't really sure where to post...

Around 2012 or so, Ramesh Raskar gave a TED talk about a femtosecond-camera produced at MIT. It has a good enough time-resolution to capture the motion of light (a trillion frames per second). He talks about all kinds of really neat applications, namely in being able to build computer images that can "look around corners". I've dug around and looked for what kind of research and improvements are been done in the realm of ultra-fast photography and computation and I'm curious as to whether any kinds of practical versions of this machine exist yet, but I haven't been able to find anything. With the unbelievable advances in technology the past 4 years, it seems only likely that this would be lightyears ahead today. Has any progress been made? If so, what?

Comment: It's not a camera of the sort you are used to but a combination of an ultrafast laser and, at least that's my guess, an ultrafast microchannel plate image intensifier. You could buy both technologies commercially for quite some time (decades), so the MIT device is more of a creative application than it's a new technology development in itself. If you have a hobby budget on the order of $50k+, you can build this at home, if you like.

Comment: Here is the list of their recent publications. http://cameraculture.media.mit.edu/publications/

Comment: @CuriousOne you are correct about the laser but there is no need of MCP here. You may think the process as taking pictures with normal camera in dark room with ultrashort flash light.

Comment: @hsinghal: It's a stroboscopic technique, but the camera "has to know" when to take the shot, which requires sub-ns apertures. I don't know of any other technique than MCPs that can do that. Did they come up with something smarter than that?

Comment: @CuriousOne It is a matter of basic synchronisation. I have used such camera with hand operation. start CCD one or two sec before the arrival of femtosecond laser keep the exposure time 5 sec. Laser will come and you will get your event.

Comment: @hingsal: If you keep the shutter open, the camera will integrate over the entire light path. I also don't think that a regular CCD has a fast enough (sub-ns) shutter edge. I would be delighted to learn otherwise, though.